# Adding a grid/table inside grid in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, module, grid-serlization

I'm developing a custom extension for my client. There are two tables which hold the complete data.

```
primary_table

id_primary | name | age | image
===========|======|=====|===================
    1      | Kush | 18  | a/c/aclong.jpg
    2      | Lav  | 19  | b/o/bottle.png
```

and

```
secondary_table

id_seconday | id_primary | item_name | quantity
============|============|===========|=========
    1       |   1        |  pen      |   4
    2       |   1        |  pencil   |   2
    3       |   2        |  eraser   |   1
    4       |   2        | sharpner  |   1
    5       |   2        |  ruler    |   2
```

I am able to show custom form to user and save the data. But while showing the data in the admin, I have a problem. As the normal Grid in the admin is simply a 2-D table, how can I display the details all at once?

One approach I think is to display the `secondary_table` data as a table in one of the columns of the Grid. But how I can achieve that? How to make a table in a column of the grid? Or how to display this data simply?

Sample Display that I want.

```
Primary ID | Name | Age | Image |           Secondary Data
===========|======|=====|=======|=======================================
           |      |     |       |  Item Name | Quantity
    1      | Kush | 18  | ****  | -----------|---------   
           |      |     |       |    Pen     |    4
           |      |     |       |    Pencil  |    2
-----------|------|-----|-------|---------------------------------------
           |      |     |       |  Item Name | Quantity
     2     | Lav  | 19  | ****  | -----------|----------
           |      |     |       |    Eraser  |    1
           |      |     |       |   Sharpner |    1
           |      |     |       |    Ruler   |    2
```

I have a working code to display everything except the last `Secondary Data` column. The code is same as the one created with `moduleCreator`. Please help me with that last column. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see here you need a table inside a column.
You could make a method that returns the value for secondary data as a html table.

So if you have the column definition like this:

```
   $this->addColumn('column_id', array(
        'header'    => $this->__('Column label'),
        'index'     => 'column_code',
    ));
```

you need to add a getter membmer

```
    $this->addColumn('column_id', array(
        'header'    => $this->__('Column label'),
        'index'     => 'column_code',
        'getter'    => 'getFormatedValues'
    ));
```

Now on  your main model you need to implement the `getFormatedValues` method that will return the data you need, wrapped in a table:

```
public function getFormatedValues() {
    return '<table><tr><td>....YOUR DATA HERE</td></tr></table>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was already trying this. I'm stuck at how to run the query prepared using following statements. `$collection = Mage::getModel('prescription/prescriptiondata')->getCollection();
  $collection->getSelect()->where("main_table.id = $value");
  ` and then how to retrieve the data to display in the table.

Comment: `$collection->getData();` is what I wanted. Thank you.